How to correctly read a csv file with single quotes and commas
I'm reading two sets of data from two variables to simulate how csv.reader would or should work but I'm not getting the desired output with string that have mmultiple commas and single quotes.
Code:
import csv

value_no_comma_or_single_quote = "This is the first, This is the second"
value_comma_and_single_quote = "'This, is, the, first', 'This, is, the, second'"

item_1 = list(csv.reader([value_no_comma_or_single_quote], delimiter=',', quotechar="'"))[0]

item_2 = list(csv.reader([value_comma_and_single_quote], delimiter=',', quotechar="'"))[0]
print(item_1)
print(item_2)

Output:
output 1>>>> ['This is the first', ' This is the second']
output 2>>>> ['This, is, the, first', " 'This", ' is', ' the', " second'"]

Output 1 is fine but the desired outcome for output 2 is:
['This, is, the, first', 'This, is, the, second']

How can solve this please. Notice output 2 only has the desired outcome on the left side whereas the right side is not properly structured.
I've seen this example How to wrap a CSV column with single quotes but it doesn't appear to address commas.
Thanks

Add skipinitialspace=True to the reader calls or avoid the space after the delimiting comma.

Brilliant. Thank you Michael Butscher
